# How to convert strange character from web page?

Tags: java, character-encoding

In the web page, it is "Why don't we" as follows:

[image]

But when I parse the webpage and save it to a text file, it becomes this under eclipse:

Why don鈥檛 we

More information about my implementation:

The webpage is: utf-8
I use jSoup to parse, the file is saved as a txt. 
I use `FileWriter f = new FileWriter()` to write to file.

UPDATE: 
I actually solve the display problem in eclipse by changing eclipse's encoding to utf-8.

Comment: How are you parsing the web page? What encoding are you using when you decode, and what encoding is the server advertising? How are you are *saving* the file afterwards? Then how are you trying to view it? Lots and lots of detail missing at the moment...

Comment: Please provide this *and the rest of the information I asked for* in the question (not just in comments - the question should stand alone). A short but complete program demonstrating the problem would be a *very* good start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FileWriter is a utility class that uses the default current platform encoding. That is non-portable, and probably incorrect.

```
BufferedWriter f = new BufferedWriter(New OutputStreamWriter(
        new FileOutputStream(file), StandardCharsets.UTF_9));
f,Write("\uFEFF"); // Redundant BOM character might be written to be sure 
                   // the text is read as UTF-8
...
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually solved the display problem. I guess my question now is: why I save a ' in wordpress, but it becomes ’. They are different, one has unicode 8817, and the other is 39.

Comment: For some single-byte ANSI encoding, allowing only 256 characters, there is a partial mapping of Unicode codes to the single-byte encoding. That mapping means that no better fitting quote is available. In general one may be happy not getting question marks as place holders of unmappable chars.